# Javascript personalized function

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions

I need to know how to make something like a `jQuery` `function`, not with the CSS selectors, just like this:

```
function getId( item )  {
    return document.getElementById( item );
}

getId('elementID').firstFunction('property').secondFunction('property');
```

but I don't know how exactly do I send `getId` result to `firstFunction` to make something to the `getId()` element and then make the `secondFunction` work, I've been trying with `prototype` but I can't make it work.

Comment: You can have a look at how jQuery deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to ensure that all of your methods that you want to be able to chain accept the same context as they output, in your case a DOM element.

So, `firstFunction` and `secondFunction` should both expect `this` to be a DOM element and should return the DOM element as well. This means, however, they you will need to modify the built in DOM element object and add your own methods, which is [generally a bad idea](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). This is why jQuery wraps everything in a wrapper object that contains the methods available as an API. Those methods all act on `this` (which must be of the same special object type) and return a (usually modified) object of the same type.

Check out a lighter-weight example here: http://buildingwebapps.blogspot.com/2012/01/creating-lightweight-dom-javascript.html and some additional reading here: http://kendsnyder.com/posts/element-wrappers-in-javascript